# Get Checkbox index in a ListView in nativescript-vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I have a checkbox inside a `ListView` component that has a `for loop`

I need to get the index number of the checked item so I can remove/modify it in the array but I'm unable to do that as there's no `:key` prop like in Vue.

This is how I'm rendering the list. I'm still new to mobile apps development so I'm not sure whether to use a `Label` with the checkboxes or just use the `text` attribute to add the text. WHat is the normal convention here?

I can get the index number of the item with `@itemTap` on `ListView` . However, it stops working when I add `@checkedChange` to the `CheckBox` tag.

Also something minor I found, I am unable to tap the checkbox to change its state (click in my case since im using an emulator). I have to tap on the text associated with it `:text="task.title"` and if I remove the text, I have no way to toggle its state.

```
<ListView for="(task, index) in tasks" @itemTap="onLabelTap">
    <v-template>
        <GridLayout columns="auto,*">
            <!-- Shows the list item label in the default color and style. -->
            <CheckBox :text="task.title" :checked="task.isChecked" @checkedChange="onCheckChange" col="0" />
            <!--<Label :text="task.text" class="item" col="1" />-->
        </GridLayout>
    </v-template>
</ListView>
```

The javascript

```
data() {
    return {
        tasks: [
            {'id': 0, 'title': 'One', isChecked: false},
            {'id': 1, 'title': 'Two', isChecked: true},
            {'id': 2, 'title': 'Three', isChecked: false}
        ],
    }
},
computed: {
    message() {
        return "<!-- Tasks Page -->";
    }
},
methods: {
    onDrawerButtonTap() {
        utils.showDrawer();
    },
    onLabelTap(event) {
        alert('You clicked on ' + event.index) // I can access `event.index` here
            .then(() => {
                console.log("Alert dialog closed.");
            });
    },
    onCheckChange(event) {
        this.isChecked = event.value;
        console.log(this.isChecked);
        console.log(event.index); // but I can't access it here
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you simply pass the task item or index itself to the event handler, something like `@checkedChange="onCheckChange(task, index)"`.

Comment: @Manoj nevermind, it worked like you said. I needed to pass `$event` as an argument as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the events on ListView will give you the index of the item tapped on the [event object](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/_ui_list_view_.itemeventdata).

For any events on individual UI components, you may pass the parameters manually. Something like,

```
<ListView for="(task, index) in tasks" @itemTap="onLabelTap">
    <v-template>
        <GridLayout columns="auto,*">
            <!-- Shows the list item label in the default color and style. -->
            <CheckBox :text="task.title" :checked="task.isChecked" @checkedChange="onCheckChange(task, index, $event)" col="0" />
            <!--<Label :text="task.text" class="item" col="1" />-->
        </GridLayout>
    </v-template>
</ListView>
```